# 0% code coverage jacoco4sbt 2.0.0, sbt 0.12.2

Tags: java, scala, sbt, jacoco

I have an sbt scala project, but actually I have only java code, and I am using junit for testing. I added the jacoco4sbt 2.0.0 plugin, but I am in the following situation:

in project_folder/src/test/java i have the following test packages:
ftest,
map,
util

- When I am running sbt test, all my tests are run and compiled (55 in total)
- When I run jacoco:cover in sbt only the 13 tests included in the util package are run, and have a percentage greater than 0 in my jacoco html report, the rest of the tests part of ftest and map package have a 0% coverage.

Any idea why is this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Good news, just solved it by luck.
sbt doesn't recognize junit tests so we are using junit-interface as a dependency in build.sbt for making them detectable. 
It turns out that junit-interface 0.9 that I was using, wasn't collaborating well with jacoco plugin, but I solved the issue just by downgrading to junit-interface 0.8.
Any explanation why downgrading solved my issue?

Comment: Could you add your comment as an answer since you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news, just solved it by luck. sbt doesn't recognize junit tests so we are using junit-interface as a dependency in build.sbt for making them detectable. It turns out that junit-interface 0.9 that I was using, wasn't collaborating well with jacoco plugin, but I solved the issue just by downgrading to junit-interface 0.8.